# PHP for Sonoma unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer

Tags: php, codesign, macos-sonoma

I'm trying to sign PHP library por Sonoma and errors founds with code sign command

The steps I followed are:

1. Created Certificate Authority for codesignin named CA for PHP
2. Created Code signing signature named User for PHP
3. Downloaded php using MacPorts /opt/local/lib/apache2/modules/mod_php83.so
4. When trying to sign using Code signing signature:

codesign --sign "User for PHP" --force --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /opt/local/lib/apache2/modules/mod_php83.so

error appears:

Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "User for PHP"
/opt/local/lib/apache2/modules/mod_php83.so: errSecInternalComponent

5. I'm gonna try with Certificate Authority, I'm not sure if is OK:

sudo codesign --sign "CA for PHP" --force --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /opt/local/lib/apache2/modules/mod_php83.so
/opt/local/lib/apache2/modules/mod_php83.so: errSecInternalComponent